# Face detection using HaarCascades throws (-215:Assertion failed) scaleFactor > 1 && _image.depth() == CV_8U in function 'detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, face-detection

I have a problem while using HaarCascades to detect a face in the photo. I get this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1389: error: (-215:Assertion failed) scaleFactor > 1 && _image.depth() == CV_8U in function 'detectMultiScale'
```

Here is my function:

```
def face_detector(img):

    color_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(os.path.join(cv2.data.haarcascades, 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))

    scale = 1.3
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(color_img, scale, 5)

    if len(faces) == 0:
        while scale != 0.0:
            x = 0.1
            scale = scale - x
            faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(color_img, scale, 5)
            if len(faces) != 0:
                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(color_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 255), 2)
                    roi = color_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

                    cv2_imshow(color_img)
                    cv2_imshow(roi)

                    return color_img, roi

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(color_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 255), 2)
        roi = color_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        cv2_imshow(color_img)
        cv2_imshow(roi)

        return color_img, roi

    return color_img, None
```

It happens only sometimes (not for all images). What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The failed assertion was:

`(-215:Assertion failed) scaleFactor > 1 && _image.depth() == CV_8U in function 'detectMultiScale'`

Both conditions must be true. At least one of them was false.

The `scale` factor needs to be larger than 1. Your code reduces it below that.

Your code also calls `detectMultiScale()` repeatedly on the same image, with varying scale factors. That is unreasonable. Pick a scale factor that is suitably close to 1, then run detection only once. `1.3` may be too big a step. Try `1.2` or `1.1`. Don't go too close or it'll just waste time for no practical gain.